# How to use RegDeleteTree to delete KEY_WOW64_64KEY key?

Tags: winapi, 64-bit, registry

I have tested `RegDeleteTree()` in 32bit program. It only delete the `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` key. Is there a function like `RegOpenKeyEx()` to specify the `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` or `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` ?

I have tired this code:

```
HKEY key = NULL;
if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\asd"), 0, KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &key) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    long d = RegDeleteTree(key, NULL);

    if (d != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << "Error" << d;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Success";
    }
}
```

The output is Success but the key still exits in registry. I'm running it on Windows 7 with VS 2013 and compiled as win32 program not x64.

Comment: I believe you just need to set the [appropriate flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724878(v=vs.85).aspx) on a `RegOpenKeyEx()` call and use the returned handle as a parameter to `RegDeleteTree()`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis However , it doesn't work.

Comment: @zzy: define "doesn't work". What are you trying to achieve? What does your actual code look like? What are you expecting to happen,and what is it actually (not) doing? Are there any error codes being reported?

Answer (score 0):

Use `RegOpenKeyEx` with `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` to open the 64 bit view of the key. Then call `RegDeleteTree` passing the returned key.

---

Regarding your update. You only ask for read access when opening the key. The documentation for `RegDeleteTree` states:

> The key must have been opened with the following access rights: DELETE, KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS, and KEY_QUERY_VALUE.

The fact that the call succeeds anyway makes me think that your process is subject to virtualization. You need to have a manifest for the process that forces UAC elevation. Use the `requireAdministrator` option in the manifest.